# Как развернуть ссылки блока по которому кликнули

Tags: jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```js
$('.open-block-biz').click(function(e) {
  $(this).find('.link').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bx-shadow">
  <div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="link" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="bx-shadow">
  <div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок 2</div>
  <div class="link" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но ничего не происходит... В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Проблема в том, что `.find` ищет элементы в родителе. Получается у вас `.link` ищется в `.open-block-biz`. Используйте ответ **Igor**, в его ответе скрипт возвращается от `.open-block-biz` к его родителю `.bx-shadow` и от него ищет `.link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ищет внутри дочерних элементов.

Клик производится по элементу

```
<div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок</div>
```

Соответственно внутри него и осуществляется поиск, и, так как, в нем нет нужных элементов - ничего не происходит.

---

Так как нужно показывать элемент, который *следует* за нажимаемым, для его выделения можно воспользоваться методом [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```js
$('.open-block-biz').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next('.link').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bx-shadow">
  <div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="link" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="bx-shadow">
  <div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок 2</div>
  <div class="link" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.open-block-biz').click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest(".bx-shadow").find('.link').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bx-shadow">
  <div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="link" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bx-shadow">
  <div class="title mt-20 open-block-biz">Заголовок 2</div>
  <div class="link" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```